# how can i import dlib on spyder using conda?

Tags: python, conda, environment, dlib, virtual-environment

I have been trying to import dlib, cv2, and os into my python project. I have successfully downloaded cv2 and os on the base(root) environment on conda, but i couldn't do it with dlib, so i created a virtual environment to download it, which worked. Now what i know the answer to is, when i wanna import all three at the same time, how can i access both the environments? I am currently using the base environment and therefore was able to import cv2 and os, but when it try it with dlib, i keep getting the error message "no module named 'delib'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used a **virtual environment** to install `dlib`, it can only be accessed inside that specific environment and not anywhere else.

You can install both `cv2` and `os` in the above-mentioned virtual environment and use it for your further works instead of using the base environment.

Comment: I am using spyder in conda. but when i create a new environment, i have to reinstall it. do i have to do this every time i wanna import new libraries? because that seems unpractical. Is there no way to include dlib in the base?

Comment: Actually, I tried installing `dlib` in my base environment and it worked fine. Please make sure that you install `Cmake` too since it doesn't automatically install it.

`pip install Cmake`

It should work fine with that.

One piece of advice though, you should consider using Virtual Environments for your Machine Learning projects. It isn't a necessity for Jupyter Notebooks but it's always safer to use one. You never know when you'll get a dependency error and your environment will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment for your project, and include the packages you require, plus the `spyder-kernels` package. For example,

```bash
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.9 opencv dlib spyder-kernels
```

Launch Spyder from wherever you have it installed (sounds like **base**).  Once Spyder launches, point the Python interpreter to the Python located in the new environment.

Such a workflow is recommended practice (rather than installing Spyder in every environment). Note you only ever need one installation an IDE like Spyder, Jupyter, etc., so good practice is to have it in a separate dedicated environment. Details on this workflow can be found in [the Spyder Documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder).